# Complex XML XSLT Query Like SQL Joins

Tags: xml, xslt, join, xpath, xalan

We have an XML file with the format shown below.

```
<toploop id="iamroot">
    <firstinner>
        <inner1 Sequence="001">
          <Number>321</Number>
        </inner1>
        <inner1 Sequence="002">
          <Number>345</Number>
        </inner1>
    </firstinner>
    <secondinner>
        <inner2 Sequence="001">
          <Number>321</Number>
          <secondNumber>189</secondNumber>
        </inner2>
        <inner2 Sequence="002">
          <Number>345</Number>
          <secondNumber>998</secondNumber>
        </inner2>
    </secondinner>
</toploop>
```

I have tried many a things, but being new to XSLT/XPath, I am not able to get a query to represent the data like below.

```
iamroot,001,321,189
iamroot,002,345,998
```

As you can observe I want to check if the firstinner tag's inner1 sequence, number matches with the secondinner tag's inner2 sequence, number then pull the secondinner tag's inner2's secondNumber tag value along side of these. Just like a two table Inner join in SQL. Can we do this in XSLT? I was trying with value matching but I dont know how to match the data in the same XML file. Please help. Thanks in advance. I am using Xalan-C for the same.

**Update:** Thanks Kay and LarsH. I tried the following script.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output  method="text" />
<xsl:template match="inner2" />   
<xsl:template match="inner1">
<xsl:variable name="inner2" select="../../secondinner/inner2[Number = current()/Number and @Sequence = current()/@Sequence]"/>   
<xsl:if test="$inner2">     
<xsl:value-of select="concat(/toploop/@id, ',', /toploop/firstinner/inner1/@Sequence, ',', /toploop/firstinner/inner1/Number, ',', $inner2/secondNumber, ',')" />
</xsl:if> 
</xsl:template> 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Its giving the output like below.

```
    iamroot,001,321,189,
    iamroot,002,345,998,
```

How can I make this formatting look like below with out the leading spaces before the records and unnecessary lines above and below the data rows.

iamroot,001,321,189,

iamroot,002,345,998,

Thanks again.

Comment: Odd question, but is the `Number` element always duplicated in `firstinner` and `secondinner`? If so, it's almost trivial, you just ignore `firstinner` altogether, but it seems unlikely it's that simple.

Comment: Actually there are some other fields inside firstinner tag which needs to be added as well.

Answer (score 4):

Something like this:

```
<xsl:template match="inner1">
  <xsl:variable name="inner2" 
   select="../../secondinner/inner2[Number = current()/Number 
                                    and @Sequence = current()/@Sequence"/>
  <xsl:if test="$inner2">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(../../@id, ',', @Sequence, ',', 
                          Number, ',', $inner2/secondNumber"/>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Here you are doing a join between two things, with `.` bound to one of them and `current()` to the other.

For a more general solution that allows joins between three or more node-sets, you can bind explicit variables, for example `<xsl:variable name="one" select="."/>`.

Comment: Thanks Kay. I have tried with similar script. But not able to get the formatting right. Can you please help? I have updated the details in the question.

Comment: @Enjoy: I believe the `@inner2` is supposed to be `$inner2`.

Answer (score 1):

Besides fixing the typo where `@inner2` should be `$inner2`...

You also need to add a template to "swallow" the elements that you don't want to process. Right now, the default template is copying the string content of all elements other than inner1 to the output. So you need to override that default template, at least for inner2 elements:

```
<xsl:template match="inner2" />
```

The fact that this template is empty means that `<inner2>` elements will be consumed without outputting anything, and without processing their descendants.

Comment: Thanks LarsH for the correction. It is working except for the formatting. Its still spitting the two matched numbers and is not in usual flat file format. Can you please help?

Comment: @Enjoy, I think you misunderstood my answer... you changed the template that had `match="inner1"` to have `match="inner2"`. Instead, you need to *add* the above empty template that has `match="inner2"`, alongside (before or after) the template you already had for `match="inner1"`.

Comment: Thanks LarsH. I have updated the script in the question. But I am still facing the formatting problems. It is giving me unnecessary spaces before the data records and extra lines before and after the records. Is that some thing to do with the XML file?

Comment: @Enjoy: I'm pretty sure it doesn't have to do with the XML file. I don't think it has to do with your `inner1` template either, though I could be wrong. I would remove the `indent="yes"` from your output method, and see if that helps.

Comment: I tried that by trying both removing indent or by keeping the indent="no". But still its not giving the required format. I am searching for this issue resolution.

Comment: Is your XML input file, XSLT, and output, exactly as shown in your question? E.g. you mentioned extra lines, yet the output shown in your question does not have extra lines.

Comment: The extra lines given in the output are removed when I pasted it in SO.

Comment: I just tried removing all spaces from the XML file between the tags and made all the data into one and only single line with out spaces between the tags of source XML file and it is giving the data in the expected format. So this proves that it is due to XML spaces. How can I suppress them? Thanks for your support through out... :)

Comment: OK, I understand now. Add this to your stylesheet, before the first template: `<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>`

Comment: That worked. Thanks LarsH. I was looking if there is a parameter which I can set this way. You made it easy for me. Thanks again. But I did not see this kind of behavior before with other XML files. May be some thing different with this file.

Comment: @Enjoy: that could depend on what templates you had. (You're welcome.)